# design pattern for parent-child structure

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx

I'm working on a project using JavaFX and classes have typically as many as 800-1200 lines . We are using fxml for displaying Node elements, still this classes are very complex. Here is concretely what I ask:

A class `ReservationUI` contains sub parts  , which are modulerized as inner classes at the moment.which again has sub parts. And this classes has access to fields of `ReservationUI` . Now I like to extract them to their own classes but now I need to have access to parent class .

```
class A{
  int x; int y;
  B b;
  public A(){
    b = new B();
    b.display();
  }
  private class B{
    private C c;
   /* modify x */ 
  }

  private class C{ 
  /* modify x and y */
  }
}
```

And when i extract them now I have dependencies even worse :

```
class A {
int x; int y; 
B b;
  public A(){
    b = new B(this);
    b.display();
  }
}
class B {
  C c;
  A a;
  public B ( A parent ){ 
  c = new C(this, parent);
  a = parent;
  /* call A.modifyX(c.get) */
}

class C{
  A a;
  B b;
  public C( B parent , A root){
   a = root;
   b = parent;
  }
}
```

What I think is here the modularization is gone terribly wrong. Especially when I have relations long as this one : root -> child -> child -> child ... .

Is there a design pattern to address this issue. As far as I know there is Mediator pattern but use of it, still doesn't bring much since I still need to basically do the same thing .

Comment: 'Composite' is a good one, isn't it? You can also look at 'Decorator'. These two handle parent-child hierarchies.

Comment: @Zhuinden well, no . Composite is fine when parent-child behave similarly. In my case i need to modify specific parent. same apply to decorator as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is to use some kind of dependency injection. The controller then resolves dependencies automatically. I assume that you don't need any enterprise framework that provides it, so you have to resolve dependencies manually somehow.

The purpose of mediator pattern is to simply encapsulate dependency mamagement in one single place. In my solution, root element A acts just as mediator. Side offect of it, is that child elements exist in short period in an uninitialized state. To solve this issue you can also introduce Builder pattern.

```
interface IA{
    /*...*/
    void modifyX(int x);
}
class A implements IA{
  int x; int y; 
  IB b;
  IC c;
  public A(){
    b = new B();
    c = new C();
    resolveDependencies();
    b.init();
    b.display();
  }
  public void resolveDependencies(){
    b.setC(c);
    b.setA(this);
    c.setA(this);
    c.setB(b);
  }
}
interface IB {
    void setC(IC c);
    void setA(IA a);
    void init();
    void display();
}
class B implements IB{
  IC c;
  IA a;
  public B (){ 
  }
  @Override
  public void setC(IC c){
    this.c = c;
  }
  @Override
  public void setA(IA a){
    this.a = a;
  }
  @Override
  public void init(){
    /* call A.modifyX(c.get) */
  }
}
interface IC {
    void setA(IA a);
    void setB(IB b);
}
class C implements IC{
  IA a;
  IB b;
  public C( ){
  }
  @Override
  public void setA(IA a){
    this.a = a;
  }
  @Override
  public void setB(IB b){
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dependency Injection is probably what you need. Have a look at the [afterburner.fx](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx) framework for managing dependency injection via annotations, which will massively reduce the amount of code you need to write in something like this.